# How can I show a ProgressRing control ONLY on top of/overlaying my current page?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm an Android developer trying to learn UWP development, and stuck on this simple need.  I have 3 pages and want to make a ProgressRing accessible to all 3 pages, so when I'm doing an async task I can pop up the ProgressRing modal.  I don't want to have ProgressRing code in each page. How can I accomplish this?

I've looked into the ContentDialog class, but that seems to require a button in the UI and all I want to show is the ProgressRing itself without a button centered in my window

The Flyout class seems like it's required to be a part of page itself so I cannot share it among multiple pages.

The Popup class looks promising but it's not modal and I cannot understand it's documentation.

Can someone recommend a class or approach for me?  How can I just overlay a control on top of my existing page, in the center of the page with no other UI just the single control, in my case a ProgressRing?

Comment: You could the progress ring in your MainPage rather than in the sub-pages. That way, it will remain as the sub-pages swap in and out.

Comment: Yes Raymond I considered that as a solution and was able to get it working using an event aggregator (https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html).  It there an easier way to have one ViewModel call another ViewModel classes methods? Seems like a LOT of work for such a simple need.

Comment: I'm old school. I would just have a method on the MainPage to hide/show the progress ring. Each page calls the method as appropriate for the scenario.

Comment: Thanks Raymond.  I did as you suggested, but found event aggregation as the only way to have one viewModel call another viewModel's methods, and that seemed like overkill to me. My current method was to create a ProgressService class, and thanks to Prism's dependency injection it was fairly easy to request the service from each viewModel. My problem there is I haven't figured out how to create a transparent dialog to place the progressRing, so right now my progress ring sits on a contentDialog which is required to have a title and button (ugly).

Comment: @szaske Does the following answer work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I show a ProgressRing control ONLY on top of/overlaying my current page?

For your requirement, It looks that you want make HUD for uwp. And you could use `Popup` class to approach. `Popup` is a general purpose container for hosting `UIElement` on top of existing content. So, you could create a `UserControl` that with `ProgressRing` and make Popup as host container.

**Code behind**

```
public sealed partial class UWPHUDControl : UserControl
{
    Popup popup;
    public UWPHUDControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();                  
    }

    public  UWPHUDControl(string message)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += UWPHUD_BackRequested;
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
        msg_Txt.Text = message;
    }

    private void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(CoreWindow sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        UpdateUI();
    }

    private void UWPHUD_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();

    }
    private void UpdateUI()
    {

        var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
        this.Width = bounds.Width;
        this.Height = bounds.Height;
    }

    public void Show()
    {       
        popup = new Popup();
        popup.Child = this;   
        progress_R.IsActive = true;       
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        UpdateUI();
    }



    public void Close()
    {
        if (popup.IsOpen)
        {
            progress_R.IsActive = false;
            popup.IsOpen = false;
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= UWPHUD_BackRequested;
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged -= CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid Name="mask_grid" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAccentAcrylicWindowAccentMediumHighBrush}" Opacity="0.35">
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        >
        <ProgressRing
            Name="progress_R"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            />
        <TextBlock
            Name="msg_Txt"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="12"
            Foreground="Azure"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

**Usage**

```
UWPHUDControl hud = new UWPHUDControl("Loading");
hud.Show();
await Task.Delay(2000);
hud.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible Steps:

1. Right-click the project.
2. Add > New Item > User Control
3. Inside your CustomUserControl xaml you can add your ProgressRing control which only needs to be customized once. To use this CustomUserControl on any of your pages.

That's a pretty basic way to do it.

Comment: Can a User Control be placed on top of the UI in the view?  I'm guessing it needs to be inserted into the view, not like a dialog that can sit on top of a page/view. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a UserControl and put this user control in the top of your UI making this visible or collapsed depending of your logic.

If you are looking for a good control to do that you can consider
Loading Xaml Control from Community Toolkit
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/loading