# How to write a InAppNotification helper, so I can call it everywhere

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Currently, I'm using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.InAppNotification` in every pages I need to toast. Like,

```
<Page>
    <Grid>

        //some else code
        <controls:InAppNotification />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is annoying, I have to write it page by page.
How to wrap it in a user control or helper, so I just need to call the helper.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351260/7254781) reply, For your requirement, you could make **HUD** for your UWP app base on `Popup` class that could implement in code behind without xaml. And you could also use above control but need to edit the app's navigation architecture. For example if you used `NavigationView` as the base `architecture` and you could place `InAppNotification` in the `MainPage`, when you need to show  `InAppNotification` you need send event to the MainPage from other page  with [MessagingCenter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MessagingCenter.cs#L23).

Comment: I used the second mehtod, place it in ShellPage.xaml.