# How do I wrap a ContentDialog in a custom Control?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui, winui-3, contentdialog

I'm trying to make a re-usable WinUI dialog to display progress information, but I want the fact that I'm using a `ContentDialog` to be an implementation detail and not expose its API. I figured I could do this by deriving from `Control` and creating a `ContentDialog` inside of its `ControlTemplate`.

Something like this:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PART_Dialog, Type = typeof(ContentDialog))]
public class ProgressDialog : Control
{
    private const string PART_Dialog = "PART_Dialog";

    private ContentDialog _dialog;

    public ProgressDialog()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ProgressDialog);
    }

    public async Task ShowAsync()
    {
        if (_dialog != null)
        {
            _ = await _dialog.ShowAsync(ContentDialogPlacement.Popup);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _dialog = GetTemplateChild(PART_Dialog) as ContentDialog;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

With a style defined like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="local:ProgressDialog" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultProgressDialog}" />

    <Style x:Key="DefaultProgressDialog" TargetType="local:ProgressDialog">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ProgressDialog">
                    <ContentDialog x:Name="PART_Dialog">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="Hello, world!" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ContentDialog>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then I would show the dialog like a `ContentDialog`:

```
var dialog = new ProgressDialog();
dialog.XamlRoot = this.XamlRoot;
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

I have the resource dictionary specified in Generic.xaml, but the control doesn't even attempt to load the template. My `OnApplyTemplate` method is never called, so `_dialog` doesn't get wired up. I assume this is because I'm not actually creating the control in the visual tree, but then how does `ContentDialog` do it?

If I call `ApplyTemplate()` myself in `ShowAsync()`, it returns `false` and the template still isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I wrap a ContentDialog in a custom Control?

Derive from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate?view=winrt-20348)

> Run code that can only work once the XAML-defined visual tree from templates has been applied. For example, code that obtains references to named elements that came from a template, by calling GetTemplateChild, so that members of these parts can be referenced by other post-template runtime code.

If you just implement, but not add into visual tree. `OnApplyTemplate` will not be invoke, and  `GetTemplateChild` will return null. please declare in the xaml like the following.

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Open" />
    <local:ProgressDialog x:Name="Dialog" />
</Grid>
```

Or make a class that inherit ContentDialog directly, for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-20348).

Comment: It indeed works if I instantiate the control in XAML, but I'm not required to do that with ContentDialog. So what is it doing that allows it to load a template without being in the visual tree? Does it add itself to the tree? Is that why it requires XamlRoot to be set?

Comment: `XamlRoot`  Represents a tree of XAML content and information about the context in which it is hosted. if you have not insert to xaml, it will not work.

Comment: You may refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351260/7254781) to make the custom dialog.